# Error when use ngFor to loop an array of object with no initialize data

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm using ngFor to loop through an array object but when the component start its has no data

```
person : personInfo[] = []
```

And this is the interface

```
 personInfo : {
           schoolInfo : {...}[]
           homeInfo : {...}[]
     }
```

and this is html code:

```
<ng-container [matColumDef]="colum.name"
 *ngFor="let column of person.shoolInfo"> //Property 'schoolInfo' does not exist on type personInfo
 <th>...</th>
 <td>...</td>
 </ng-container>
```

The `person` data will have when I trigger an button event but at the start `person` have no data to assign and I got the error like above

```
//Property 'schoolInfo' does not exist on type personInfo
```

What do I need to do to solve this problem? and thanks for your time

Comment: You can use also the "safe operator" `?`: `<ng-container ...*ngFor="let column of person?.schoolInfo">`, but to define an interface you need remove the ":", e.g. `interface personInfo{schoolInfo:number[]}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your usage for a person, the person must be an Object not an Array.

```
person: personInfo = {
  schoolInfo: []
  homeInfo: []
}
```

And then you can use it in ngFor without any problem.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution will be if you have multiple persons, you can generate multiple tables,

```
// person : personInfo[] = []; - this was written
persons : personInfo[] = []; // instead make it persons
```

In the HTML or template let's make the changes accordingly to make this code work.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let person of persons">
  <ng-container [matColumDef]="colum.name" 
    *ngFor="let column of person.shoolInfo"> 
    //Property 'schoolInfo' does not exist on type personInfo

    <th>...</th>
    <td>...</td>
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```